# Binning error for a dataframe column - KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([61.5, 59.8, 56.8.... dtype='float64', length=53940)] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I wrote a function for binning the numerical values of a dataframe column, i.e., dividing the column values into the specified number of categories.

```
def binning_fun(df, col_name, num_of_bins):
    lt=[]
    for i in range(0,num_of_bins):
        lt.append(i)
        df[col_name]=pd.cut(df[col_name],bins=i+1, labels=lt)
    return df

df="C:/Users/shootings.csv"
binning_fun(df, df['depth'], 4)
```

This gives the following error:

**"None of [Float64Index([61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.4, 63.3, 62.8, 62.3, 61.9, 65.1, 59.4,\n              ...\n              60.5, 59.8, 60.5, 61.2, 62.7, 60.8, 63.1, 62.8, 61.0, 62.2],\n             dtype='float64', length=53940)] are in the [columns]"**

These values do exist in the column 'depth'. Why are they being called inexistent?

My dataset:

```
        carat   cut     clarity  depth  table   
0       0.23    Ideal       SI2  61.5   55.0    
1       0.21    Premium     SI1  59.8   61.0    
2       0.23    Good        VS1  56.9   65.0    
3       0.29    Premium     VS2  62.4   58.0    
4       0.31    Good        SI2  63.3   58.0    
5       0.24    Good        VVS2 90.7   62.8
```

Expected output:

```
depth
1
0
0
1
1
2
```

Comment: It seems from your post that df is just a string: df="C:/Users/shootings.csv". Also could you provide an extract of df so we can try your code on it?

Comment: I edited my question to include a sample of my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for fixed bin sizes:

```
def binning_fun(df, col_name, num_of_bins):
    df[col_name]=pd.cut(df[col_name], bins=num_of_bins, labels=range(num_of_bins))
    return df

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/shootings.csv")
binning_fun(df, 'depth', 4)
```

Output:

```
    carat   cut     clarity  depth   table
0   0.23    Ideal   SI2      0       55.00
1   0.21    Premium SI1      0       61.00
2   0.23    Good    VS1      0       65.00
3   0.29    Premium VS2      0       58.00
4   0.31    Good    SI2      0       58.00
5   0.24    Good    VVS2     3       62.80
```

Or use [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html#pandas.qcut) for equal-sized buckets:

```
def binning_fun(df, col_name, num_of_bins):
    df[col_name]=pd.qcut(df[col_name], q=num_of_bins, labels=range(num_of_bins))
    return df

df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/shootings.csv")
binning_fun(df, 'depth', 4)
```

Output:

```
    carat   cut     clarity depth   table
0   0.23    Ideal   SI2     1       55.00
1   0.21    Premium SI1     0       61.00
2   0.23    Good    VS1     0       65.00
3   0.29    Premium VS2     2       58.00
4   0.31    Good    SI2     3       58.00
5   0.24    Good    VVS2    3       62.80
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I edited my question to include the expected output. The binning function which I have used replaces the column values after classifying them into the specified number of categories (like, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4). The number of bins is basically the number of categories.